# dropbox object does not have Dropbox attribute in Python

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am now using Python to download files from Dropbox, and I following [this tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial). However, it did not succeed on the first two lines of codes:

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN')
```

My Python complains that `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dropbox'`  Any ideas?

Comment: did you name your file "dropbox.py"?

Comment: Ttry doing this: `print(dropbox.__file__)` after the import statement. That's two underscores on either side of `file`.  It will tell you what file is being imported. Most likely, the file you're importing is not the actual dropbox module, but something else.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, but it is not the case. The print output is: C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\dropbox\__init__.pyc

Comment: This weird as it is a common case, in case we have a .py in the dir with same name as of the module we import i.e. wrong module get imported - check the site-packages dir if you have more than dropbox folders there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful examination, I found the reason is because I am using functions from dropbox-v2 while in my machine dropbox-v1 was installed.